# How to modify Firebase push notification

Tags: php, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending push notification form my server API to ios devices using google's Firebase push notification.

Right now when user receives it its structure is simple, there is a title and a message.

Can I add custom buttons in it? For example two buttons, one to accept the action and the other to reject it.

I have read the documentation but I could not find anything concerning code.

I know I am stating my problem straight away here.

Can somebody please guide me in this?

Thank You

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  I can't seem to find a way to set the "category" value of the APS payload, specifically thru the console.